# langchain streaming TypeError: Additional kwargs key output_tokens already exists in left dict and value has unsupported type <class 'int'>

Tags: langchain, large-language-model

```py
# from dotenv import load_dotenv
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain_community.llms import Tongyi

# load_dotenv()


llm = Tongyi(streaming=True, max_tokens=2048)

prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
    [("system", "你是一个专业的AI助手。"), ("human", "{query}")]
)

llm_chain = prompt | llm

ret = llm_chain.stream({"query": "你是谁？"})
for token in ret:
    print(token, end="", flush=True)
print()
```

error

[error situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5E3Cr.jpg)

I want to use LangChain to preform streaming output with TongYi's large language model, but I encontered the following error.
I can achieve streaming output functioality using Tongyi official API, but since I want to utilize subsequent features of LangChian, I hope to also use it within Lang Chain.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when using 'ChatTongYi' with streaming.
Try to fix it by following this PR:
https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/pull/16580.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,  In conclusion , should I  replace the value in libs/core/langchain_core/utils/_merge.py ?

Comment: For now, I think you should follow the new PR #16605 which be mentioned in the #16580,simply replace the old int with the new, it should be work.